# App crashes without displaying an error (FragmentPagerAdapter)

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentpageradapter, android-pageradapter

I have a `CarouselPagerAdapter` that extends `FragmentPagerAdapter`.
I have been tasked by my supervisor to add another tab(which is a fragment) in the app.

I've been trying to add a single fragment in the `CarouselPagerAdapter`but my app crashes instantly without displaying error.

Even in the simplest of cloning another fragment but changing the name of the fragment still crashes the app. I don't know the logic of this app and I'm really depressed. I hope you guys could figure out what is wrong.

this is a part of the `CarouselPagerAdapter`

```
public class CarouselPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private final Resources resources;

/**
 * Create pager adapter
 *
 * @param resources
 * @param fragmentManager
 */
List<FragmentGenerate> list=new ArrayList<FragmentGenerate>();
public CarouselPagerAdapter(final Resources resources, final FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
    super(fragmentManager);
    this.resources = resources;


    //Newly added tab

    list.add(new FragmentGenerate() {
        @Override
        public ContactFragment newInstance() {
            return ContactFragment.newInstance();
        }

        @Override
        public String instanceName() {
            return "Retrofit Sample";
        }
    });
    //END
```

this is the tab that I tried cloning `MoviesFragment`

```
public class MoviesFragment extends BaseFragment {

@Inject
protected MovieService movieService;

@InjectView(R.id.lvListHolder)
protected ListView lvMovies;


@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Injector.inject(this);
}
@Override
public View onCreateView2(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_simplelist, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated2(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    MovieAdapter adapter=new MovieAdapter(getActivity(),movieService);
    lvMovies.setAdapter(adapter);
    lvMovies.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Movie movie=(Movie)adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
            MovieActivity.start(getActivity(), movie);
        }
    });
}
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){}

//Here you Save your data
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState2(Bundle outState) {}


public static MoviesFragment newInstance(){
    return new MoviesFragment();
}
```

}

I have cloned it and just changed the fragment name and the instance name like this:

```
public class ContactFragment extends BaseFragment



public static ContactFragment newInstance(){
    return new ContactFragment();
}
```

why does it crash? It should just logically make a tab with a duplicate content but a different name. shouldn't it? Please help.

**EDIT**:
 I've fixed the previous error because the newly added fragment is missing from the "injects" of the module because the app uses Dagger Library.

**PROBLEM**:
 I created an app using retrofit 2 library and it works. When I try to add a fragment with the contents of my retrofit app, the method `getMyJSON()` is (Unknown source)

HERE IS THE LOGCAT:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                               Process: securitywizards.herobo.com.androidtemplate, PID: 11382
>                                                                                               java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: HTTP method annotation is required (e.g., @GET, @POST, etc.).
>                                                                                                   for method RetrofitService.getMyJSON
>                                                                                                   at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.methodError(ServiceMethod.java:695)
>                                                                                                   at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.methodError(ServiceMethod.java:686)
>                                                                                                   at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.build(ServiceMethod.java:173)
>                                                                                                   at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Retrofit.java:166)
>                                                                                                   at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:145)
>                                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:397)
>                                                                                                   at $Proxy0.getMyJSON(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                                   at securitywizards.herobo.com.androidtemplate.viewcontroller.fragment.samples.ContactFragment.onCreate(ContactFragment.java:58)
>                                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1763)
>                                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:913)
>                                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.performPendingDeferredStart(FragmentManager.java:842)
>                                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.setUserVisibleHint(Fragment.java:859)
>                                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.setPrimaryItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:130)
>                                                                                                   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1071)
>                                                                                                   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
>                                                                                                   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1441)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17915)
>                                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:963)
>                                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17915)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5698)
>                                                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:465)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17915)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5698)
>                                                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:465)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17915)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5698)
>                                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1692)
>                                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:760)
>                                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17915)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5698)
>                                                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:465)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17915)
>                                                                                                   at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:851)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17915)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5698)
>                                                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:465)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17915)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5698)
>                                                                                                   at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:453)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17915)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5698)
>                                                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:465)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17915)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5698)
>                                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1692)
>                                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:760)
>                                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17915)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5698)
>                                                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:465)
>                                                                                                   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2731)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17915)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2413)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1415)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1639)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.ViewR

ContactFragment:

```
public class ContactFragment extends BaseFragment {

private ListView listView;
private View parentView;

private ArrayList<Datum> datalist;
private ArrayList<Organization> datainfo;


private ContactAdapter adapter;



@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Injector.inject(this);
    RetrofitService api = Client.getApiService();

    Call<Util> call = api.getMyJSON();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<Util>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Util> call, Response<Util> response) {
            //Dismiss Dialog


            if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                datalist = response.body().getOrganization().getData();

                adapter = new ContactAdapter(getActivity(), datalist);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Util> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
@Override
public View onCreateView2(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_simplelist, container, false);
    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvListHolder);
    datalist = new ArrayList<Datum>();

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated2(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //Creating an object of our api interface

}
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){}

//Here you Save your data
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState2(Bundle outState) {}


public static ContactFragment newInstance(){
    return new ContactFragment();
}
```

}

Here is the Interface that has getMyJSON method:

```
public interface RetrofitService {

public static final String URL_GETLIST ="api/organizations?type=json";

@GET(URL_GETLIST)
Call<Util> getMyJSON();
```

}

I've included all the classes in the module:

```
@Module(
    complete = false,

    injects = {
            MainApplication.class
            ,NavigationDrawerFragment.class
            , BaseFragment.class
            , CarouselFragment.class
            , SimpleFragment.class
            , SimpleListFragment.class
            , MoviesFragment.class
            , ButtonFragment.class
            , ProgressFragment.class
            , DownloadService.class
            , MainActivity.class
            , ParallaxFragment.class
            , SwipeFragment.class
            , DaimajaSliderFragment.class
            , DatabaseListFragment.class
            , ContactFragment.class
            , MovieActivity.class
            , SweetDialogFragment.class
            , ListViewParallaxFragment.class
            , SimpleWebViewFragment.class
            , Client.class
            , Util.class  //1st Class
            , Datum.class //2nd Class
            , Organization.class //3rd Class

    }
```

)

Comment: "without displaying error"...believe me, there is no crash without an error log in your andorid monitor. You have to remove the filters, then you will see some errors...

Comment: thank you sir. I now know how to use the logcat using "Error" and "No Filters". I've seen what's missing.

Comment: ok great, can you please share the error log now?

Comment: the error was because i missed putting the fragment to the module. That's because the app uses dagger library. I've got new problem now because the logcat says (Unknown source). I'll just edit my post.

Comment: I don't know about Retrofit, i use Volley, but what i get from error your is your Http request is missing method like GET, POST, or PUT.

Comment: yes, I've seen that error. but the GET method is already stated in the Interface like the "@GET(URL_GETLIST)". I don't know how to debug that error.

Comment: I guess it is because the library I imported was the older version. I changed the library now another error pops up!. omg.